# How do I do a Redo after Undo (Ctrl+Z) in Twitter's tweet compose box?

Tags: twitter, google-chrome, linux

Normally, Ctrl+Y would "undo the undo" and put me back where I was. But in Twitter's compose tweet dialog box, Ctrl+Y does nothing.

This is on PC, Linux, Chromium browser.

Comment: I've just tried this in Chrome under Windows 7 and Ctrl+Y works as expected. I suspect this is a browser or even OS issue. Can you use Ctrl+Y on other text boxes on other sites?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `Ctrl + Shift + Z`. Tested on Linux with Chrome browser.

Answer (score -2):

I ran into the problem of accidentally undoing some formatted content on a Mac using Chrome. While **command + z** is undo, the shortcut to redo in Chrome on the Mac is **control + z**.

Comment: The question is about PC.